Is the Hilbert space of a Black Hole factorizable?
I am doing research on black hole information and have a question: Is the black hole's Hilbert space factorizable? In other words, can we write the Hilbert space of the black hole as a multiplication of at least two Hilbert spaces (associated with two subsystems)?

You can always do so if the dimensions allow it. To start with, what is the Hilbert space of a black hole?

Usually, for eternal black holes, one uses the thermofield double-state trick. This consists of doubling the field theory described in the black hole geometry to have a state $|n\rangle \otimes |m\rangle$. I am no expert in this field, but since the two copies are uncoupled in the lagrangian, this should mean the Hilbert space associated with this trick is the tensor square of the Fock space of the very field theory one uses.

Have a look at S.Giddings' A “black hole theorem” and its implications.
